# How can I paginate the Views page itself where all views are listed?

Tags: 7, views

At the url admin/structure/views how can I paginate this list of results?

Comment: what is logic behind it?

Answer (score 2):

If you have many views I would suggest you go to Views settings (`admin/structure/views/settings`) and enable **`Show filters on the list of views`**. This gives you the possibility to search and filter the list of views in various ways.